# How to plot a stacked bar chart from a pandas frame which is grouped and counted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, multi-index

My goal is to produce a simple stacked bar plot with the VALUE as the X axis, each type is the bar stacks, and the number(count) is the y value of each bar stack.

I have the result of a data frame grouping which looks like:

| VALUE | TYPE |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 0 | 16 |
|  | 1 | 26 |
|  | 2 | 15 |
|  | 3 | 18 |
| 1.0 | 1 | 15 |
|  | 2 | 2 |
|  | 3 | 10 |
| 2.0 | 0 | 10 |
|  | 1 | 175 |
|  | 2 | 99 |
|  | 3 | 11 |
|  | 15 | 100 |
| 3.0 | 0 | 92 |
|  | 1 | 20 |
|  | 2 | 17 |
|  | 3 | 26 |
|  | 15 | 1 |

Name: VALUE, dtype: int64

I created this from a large data frame by:
dataOutput = df.groupby(['VALUE','TYPE']).agg('VALUE').count()

I want to iterate through the dataframe and get access to the 'counts', and then push the uneven result into the stacked plots.

I am stuck at the looping through this data and getting access to the count.
for i, (val, typ) in enumerate(df.index):
print(val)
print(typ)

How to access count?

for val, typ in df.groupby(level=0):
print(val)
print(typ)
break

The data is there, but not sure how to access the count column.

| VALUE | TYPE |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 0 | 16 |
|  | 1 | 26 |
|  | 2 | 15 |
|  | 3 | 18 |

Is there some simpler way? Or can someone explain how I could condition this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you have a multiindex series, s, that looks like this:

```
VALUE  TYPE
0.0    0        16
       1        26
       2        15
       3        18
1.0    1        15
       2         2
       3        10
2.0    0        10
       1       175
       2        99
       3        11
       15      100
3.0    0        92
       1        20
       2        17
       3        26
       15        1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

For convenience, I renamed the series name to 'count'.

```
s.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. Yes series got me. I changed it from series back to data frame and was able to work with it, but your solution is great - one liner achieved - thank you for the reply and solution.